# Keep getting PG::UndefinedTable with namespaced Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some models set up with namespacing..

```
rails g model Technology::Post ...
```

This has led to the error

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "posts" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
               :SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                 pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
            FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
              ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
           WHERE a.attrelid = '"posts"'::regclass
             AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
           ORDER BY a.attnum
```

As these are namespaced, I have a model `technology.rb`

```
module Technology
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'technology_'
  end
end
```

And of course the `Technology::Post` model. This model is in a folder `technology` and is named `post.rb`.

```
class Technology::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

My database name is `technology_posts`.

```
public | technology_posts                  | table | postgres
```

Yet for some reason, it's looking for a table `posts`. In the controller I can just have a basic `@posts = Technology::Post.all` and this will still happen.

Restarting the server will fix the issue, until it happens again. This also is not a problem in our production environment. Only development.

Comment: So when you start the server it "fixes the issue", but after some period of time it begins to fail?

Comment: Yea when I restart it..as weird as that may seem. But by *period of time* I mean after i navigate to a page and then back.

Comment: Hmm. So it has the relation to begin with and then drops it at some point. Are you resetting the prefix anywhere? I made a very simple demo application with the same specifications, using the 'pg' gem, running on WEBRick. I get an #<ActiveRecord::Relation>. Do you know if this only happens for namespaced Models or does this happen on all of your models?

Comment: Yea I am not resetting any prefixes. This only happens for namespaced models, but it does not happen for all of them.

Comment: How are you including the Technology module in your model?

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this issue? I am seeing something similar.

Answer (score 5):

There are three a few things going on.

First, make sure you have the latest version of the pg gem.

Udit's answer, setting the table name, may work. But it's a workaround. I believe the cause of the issue and the reason why this doesn't work out of the box is the following:

When you generate a namespaced model, Rails creates a module file like the following:

```
module Technology
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'technology_'
  end
end
```

However, if you define the constant / module 'Technology' elsewhere, Rails may not autoload this file! You can test by putting some debugging `puts` at the top of the file.

The solution is to make sure that this module is loaded by explicity requiring it, or to shift it to a model. For example,

```
module Technology
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'technology_'
  end
  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
self.table_name = 'NAME OF YOUR TABLE'
```